# AWS Cloud9 wildcard environment membership

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cloud9

Is there a way to pass a wildcard user ARN to

```
aws cloud9 create-environment-membership --user-arn arn:aws:blah
```

Looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloud9/create-environment-membership.html it looks like I can only pass specific user ARNs but I'd like to be able to put wildcards in there rather than having a list of specific user ARNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible today. You have to specify a fully matched ARN for an IAM Principal (IAM User or STS Session)